# Make a DropdownList visible on click of a RadioButton

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I perform a `radiobuttonclick`, I want to set a `dropdownlist` to become visible. The `radiobutton` and `dropdownlist` are within the same `datagrid`. I am not sure how to do this.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanel" UpdateMode="conditional" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DataGrid ID="DataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns = "false" CssClass="objectSubTitle" ItemStyle-Wrap="true" runat="server" OnItemCommand="handler" ><Columns>
            <asp:TemplateColumn>
                <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:RadioButton ID ="RadioButton1" Text="Yes" GroupName="creatingNewCard" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButtonYes" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" />
                  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1"  Visible="false" runat="server"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Can you show the aspx markup of the grid where we see the DropDownList and the RadioButton? Are you really using the old DataGrid or the newer GridView (which is similar)?

Comment: Do you recommend using a GridView instead of DataGrid?

Comment: @escobar_season: They are similar, a GridView can everything that a DataGrid can but not vice-versa. Have a look here for the differences: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05yye6k9.aspx The only reason to stay with a DataGrid is  you either only have .NET 1.1. or you need to maintain an old project using ASP.NET 1.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that they are in an `ItemTemplate` of a `TemplateField` and you want to switch vivibility on serverside:

```
protected void RbCheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var radioButton1 = (RadioButton)sender;
    var row = (GridViewRow)radioButton1.NamingContainer;
    var dropDownList1 = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("DropDownList1");
    dropDownList1.Visible = radioButton1.Checked;
}
```

Sample-GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="Grid_RowDataBound"
    runat="server">
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:RadioButton  ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="RbCheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:RadioButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Edit**: as you've edited your question to show that you really use a `DataGrid` instead of a `GridView`, the code is similar:

```
protected void RbCheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var radioButton1 = (RadioButton)sender;
    var item = (DataGridItem)radioButton1.NamingContainer;
    var dropDownList1 = (DropDownList)item.FindControl("DropDownList1");
    dropDownList1.Visible = radioButton1.Checked;
}
```

Comment: What if they are in different `asp:TemplateColumn`? Would var item = `(DataGridItem)radioButton1.NamingContainer;` have to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the Visible property of the DropdwonList in the radio buttons checked changed event like this

```
protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var radioButton1= (RadioButton)sender;
    var item = (DataGridItem)radioButton1.NamingContainer;
    var dropDownList1 = (DropDownList)item.FindControl("DropDownList1");

    dropDownList1.Visible = radioButton1.Checked ? true : false;
}
```